# matlab table timestep calculation

Tags: matlab, datetime, cell

Is there a way to access the column data without having to type `table_name.VariableName (:,:)`? I need to find the delta time from the time stamp of the data. This is what I have done so far:

```
[u,v]=size(a);
b=cell2table(cell(u,1));

for i=1:u
   if i==1
       b(i,1)={'0'};
   else
       b(i,1)=(datenum(a.PCTimestamp_None_(i,1)) ...
           -datenum(a.PCTimestamp_None_(i-1,1)))+str2double(b{i-1,1});
   end
end
```

The problem, I am having is, the time stamp is always in column 1. So I am looking for a way to access data just by mentioning first column instead of variable name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See: [Access Data in a Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curly braces in order to index your table without specifying the variable name associated to the targeted column. Curly braces can also be used for a more straightforward assignment/retrieval of inner cell values.

```
[u,v] = size(a);

b = cell(u,1);
b{1} = 0;

for i = 2:u
    b{i} = (datenum(a{i,1}) - datenum(a{i-1,1})) + b{i-1};
end

b = cell2table(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Table variables can be accessed by index as `t.(1)` as well as by name

```
t = table(ones(3, 1), rand(3, 1), 'VariableNames', {'foo', 'bar'});
assert(isequal(t.bar, t.(2)));
```